# New to Python - Trying to output a dataframe to csv from Input

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, yahoo-finance

Good Morning/ Afternoon

I'm relatively new, learning some python for the finance It world.
Trying to figure out some inputs > outputs for data.

My goal is to create a CSV from the ticket input
only thing missing is it won't create a new file from said "ticker"

```
import yfinance as yf
start_date = '2020-01-01'
end_date = '2023-01-20'
ticker = input("Enter Ticker :")
data = yf.download(ticker, start_date, end_date)
print(data.tail())

# Export data to a CSV file
data.to_csv = ( '.csv')
```

Comment: The last line should be `data.to_csv("name_of_file.csv")`.

Comment: Ty for the response. I did as suggested.                                    #  Export data to a CSV file
data.to_csv = ('name_of_file.csv'), however is just named the file "name of file" my goal was to produce output based on input name.  (I.e Input IBM) = output IBM.CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matt said, you should use:

```
data.to_csv("name_of_file.csv")
```

If you wish your code to have variable csv name:

```py
input_name = "IBM"
data.to_csv(f"{input_name}.csv")
```

You need to define `input_name` though.

Comment: TY. Variable name ...I tried this input_name= ('input_name')
data.to_csv(f"{input_name}.csv")

Comment: why do you keep putting it in parentheses? just `input_name='input_name'`

Comment: TY. Variable name .
I tried this input_name= ('input_name')
data.to_csv(f"{input_name}.csv") 
however file output is input_name.csv 
Also tried 
input_name= ("ticker")
data.to_csv(f"{input_name}.csv")
my output file keeps being named input.csv

Comment: import yfinance as yf
start_date = '2020-01-01'
end_date = '2023-01-20'
ticker = input("Enter Ticker :")
data = yf.download(ticker, start_date, end_date)
print(data.tail())
# Export data to a CSV file
input_name= 'input_name'
data.to_csv(f"{input_name}.csv")

Comment: FYI- Thanks for your help folks..Much much appreciated while I work to resolve this. cheers

Comment: Thanks Patrick. It did help. though I haven't been able to get this to print out the variable name.. it keep printing out the file name as file_name_input.,even though I change to this input_name='input_name'.